# KML displays with one placemark, but not multiple

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I trying to display multiple polygons (representing watersheds) in a google maps window embedded on my website (with Google Maps API version 3).  I have a kml file which will display a single polygon, here:
http://www.unc.edu/~mmallard/show_HUC8/HUC8short.kml

Below is its structure.  A full copy can be found at the URL above, the lat/lon pairs make it too long to completely show here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
<Document>
<Placemark>
    <name>Middle Roanoke</name>
    <Style><LineStyle><width>1.5</width></LineStyle><PolyStyle><color>7dff0000</color></PolyStyle></Style>
    <Polygon>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>-78.269539986182295,36.540063430378005 ...and so on </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I then tried to use this as a template to create a kml file with multiple polygons, which is here:
http://www.unc.edu/~mmallard/show_HUC8/HUC8supported.kml

I inserted a new placemark for each watershed, and kept the same formatting as above.
However, this second file displays nothing in my google maps window.

Note that BOTH files will display in google earth, but the kml with multiple polygons (HUC8supported.kml) appears as blank my maps window.

Are there additional tags I should use or tags I should modify in order to display multiple placemarks from one kml?  Should I be using "Folder" instead of the "Document" tag?  I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Here is the website where I'm attempting to display the kml:http://www.unc.edu/~mmallard/show_HUC8/index.html

Comment: Your [kml is invalid](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.unc.edu/~mmallard/show_HUC8/HUC8supported.kml).  [KML Validator result](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unc.edu%2F~mmallard%2Fshow_HUC8%2FHUC8supported.kml) might be too big.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for checking that.  I didn't know about KML Validator.  Does this mean that I should break this file up into multiple kml's so that each one is smaller?

Comment: That would be one option. The [documented limit is 3MB](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport). You could try KMZ (your file is 9+ MB).  Don't see an issue with [the data itself](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/HUC8supported.kml)

Comment: I tried creating a kmz with this command: zip HUC8supported.kmz HUC8supported.kml     But that file also won't display.  I'll try breaking it up into the smaller files.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: A straight [zip of your KML is still bigger than 3MB](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/HUC8supported.kmz), so it is still too big.